# Can I cast opposed school spells with wild arcana?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

The rules to wild arcana say:

> The spell must be on one of your arcane class spell lists and must be
>   of a level that you can cast with that arcane spellcasting class.
>
> You don't need to have the spell prepared, nor does it need to be on
>   your list of spells known.

My opposed school is necromancy. Is it possible to use Wild Arcana to cast Enervation? The spell is of a Level I can cast (My wizard is CL 7) but I am not sure whether opposed spells are on my arcane class spell lists.

Comment: What makes you think it wouldn't be? Opposition only matters to preparing spells.

Comment: Usually I have to spend two slots for a spell from the opposition school. This is a big handicap and I thought there would be one using opposed spells with wild arcana as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The wizard class feature [arcane school](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard#TOC-Arcane-School) does *not* remove spells of the wizard's opposition schools from the wizard's spell list; were that the case, the wizard would be unable to cast [spells](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard#TOC-Spells) of opposition schools at all! Instead, spells of the opposed school simply follow a slightly different set of rules from the wizard's normal spells, like, for example, spells from opposition schools occupy two spell slots instead of one, and it's more difficult for the wizard to create magic items that incorporate spells from opposition schools than from other schools.

This means an [archmage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-heroes/mythic-paths---paizo-inc/archmage)'s supernatural ability wild arcana can be employed to allow, for example, a wizard that has picked necromancy as his opposition school to use with the ability a necromancy spell like [*enervation*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enervation).

This isn't, like, *cheesy* or anything: that wizard is a *mythic archmage!* He's *supposed* to be sort of awesome.

Comment: This seems to be one of the more relevant differences between PF and 3.5. I wouldn't be surprised if the asker came from a 3.5 background with this question, because there it would actually be a valid concern.